# How do i remove main menu title once it's in sidebar,

Tags: theming, routes

Why is so dang difficult to style the main menu once you put in the sidebar in Drupal 7?!?

i also want to remove those annoying leaf classes!  first leaf, leaf, last leaf etc.

on the page template file i see the main nav code and where it spits out title, but in the same file,
all the side bar code is in one variable. how do i access that?,

i don't mind  php coding. can someone please advise how to do this?

big thanks in advance

Comment: Did you place it in the side bar via a Block?

Comment: yes i placed in SideBar

Comment: you can override a block's title by explicitly giving it a title of <none> . As for the classes, I believe you would need to override a hook as webkenny suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wild world of theme functions, friend. You're going to need to do some overriding of the main menu in a file called "template.php" which should be included in whatever base theme you're using. Create a function in that file that looks something like this:

```
function MYTHEMENAME_menu_link($variables){ // Code here }
```

Use this link as reference to understand how to change what's there: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7

And for a real brain buster on everything you want to know about how to theme menus, check out this answer by Sheena, who's basically a genius: [Advanced menu theming in Drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24783/advanced-menu-theming-in-drupal-7)